# How can I get a list of a specified field from a Sails JS Waterline collection?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, sails.js, waterline

I have a MySQL table with a `url` column and I want to get a list of every `url` value in the table. Structure:

[image: Structure]

In PHP using Laravel I could have done something like this to get an array of every `url` column value:

```
$boards = Board::all()->lists('url');
```

However, I cannot figure out how to do this using Sails JS. I've noticed that find() without any argument gets every row in the database but I can't find anything in the documentation that would allow me to either get a list of the values for the `url` column or a way to iterate over the returned collection.

I've tried this:

```
var boards = Board.find().exec(function(error, _boards) {
  if(error)
  {
    return response.negotiate(error);
  }

  return _boards;
});
```

However, I can't actually seem to iterate over the returned data.

Any thoughts?

EDIT:

Full HomepageController.js:

```
module.exports = {
  index: function (request, response) {
    var data = {
      currentDate: (new Date()).toString(),
      boards: Board.query('SELECT url FROM board', function (error, results) {
        if (error) {
          return response.negotiate(error);
        }

        return results;
      })
    };

    return response.view('homepage', data);
  }
};
```

EDIT: Working Code:

```
module.exports = {
  index: function (request, response) {
    Board.query('SELECT url FROM board', function(error, results) {
      if(error)
      {
        return response.negotiate(error);
      }

      return response.view('homepage', { currentDate: (new Date()).toString(), boards: results });
    });
  }
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a raw [`.query()`](https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline-docs/blob/master/queries/query-methods.md#query-query-data-callback-) to select individual columns:

```
Board.query('SELECT url FROM board', function (err, results) { ... });
```

However, keep in mind that your data will still look like this:

```
[{url: 'row 1 value'}, {url: 'row 2 value'}, ...]
```

Comment: Hi, I tried what you suggested however I still cannot get the results to display in my HTML. For my HTML all I'm doing is a for loop over the 'boards' variable using Twig. I've added the code for my controller to the main post.

Comment: `Board.query` doesn't synchronously return the data, that's an asynchronous callback.. assign `results` to `data.boards` inside the callback function and then call `response.view()` also inside the callback.

Comment: Thanks, that works. This is going to take a while to get used to. Are there any recommended ways of building my controllers to simplify this? For example, if I was performing multiple queries how would I make sure they've all been completed before returning the view?

Comment: @LiamPotter My personal favorite is [async](https://www.npmjs.com/package/async). It's a library dedicated to providing utility functions for organizing asynchronous control flow. Node.js in particular tends to easily turn into pyramid code with nested callbacks within callbacks. You use async to flatten it out and eliminate hidden race conditions by organizing your code by data dependency.